# Como agrupar array e montar o select

Tags: php, array

Como posso fazer para agrupar os resultados do array e montar o select.

### Banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### PHP

```
<?php

 $rsPA = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM provas_agendadas WHERE status = 'A' ");

 foreach ($rsPA as $key => $rsRowPA){
   $dis1[] = explode("," , $rsRowPA['disciplinas']);
 }

 echo '<pre>';print_r($dis1);echo '</pre>';

?>
```

### Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => EJA-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => EJA-1
            [1] => EJA-5
            [2] => TTI-1
        )

)
```

**Explicando:** Do resultado do array, apenas irei pegar o numero depois do `-`, Ex: `EJA-1`, só preciso do `1`, que é o ID da tabela disciplina.

### Resultado final que gostaria

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço a todos que poderem me ajudar.

Comment: pesquise sobre array_search, deve resolver teu problema: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php

Comment: O nome da disciplina vai sempre seguir exatamente este modelo `<string>-<id>`? se for o caso você pode combinar as funções `substr` e `strrpos` pra extrair o id, tipo assim `$disciplina = 'eja-5'; $id = substr($disciplina, strrpos($disciplina, '-') + 1);`

Comment: @DiegoMartins sim sempre esse modelo `<string><hifen><id>`

Comment: @DiegoMartins e a montagem do select, como ficaria?

Comment: Bom aí depende muito, se você está usando alguma ferramenta de layout ou se está usando o código diretamente no html... No geral você pode contar os IDs dentro desse *foreach* que já está aí, e depois um novo *for* pra criar as tags `<option>` dentro do select.

Comment: Estou fazendo direto no html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem tiver a mesma dúvida.

```
<?php

 $rsPA = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM provas_agendadas WHERE status = 'A' ");
 foreach ($rsPA as $key => $rsRowPA){
   $temp = explode("," , $rsRowPA['disciplinas']);
   foreach($temp as $elem){
    $number = explode('-',$elem);
    $number = end($number);
    $numbers[] = $number;
   }
 }
 $dis1 = array_count_values($numbers);

 echo '<pre>';print_r($dis1);echo '</pre>';

?>
```